# Search on page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html page, and I want to find on it some data, but main trouble is that page is generated on server, and I want to write javascript code on my local machine and run it. So how can I write and run on local machine javascript code, so that it will find text, or get element by id/class?

Note, this is important: only pure javascript, no libraries like jQuerys and etc!

Thank you.

Comment: You want to inject JavaScript into a web page or integrate JavaScript into your page?

Comment: @Bakudan maybe yes) yes to inject. To run it on my machine

Comment: There are some useful extensions to control your scripts [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Mozilla and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome and as T.J. Crowder post bookmarklets are possible.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer**:

I didn't understand at first that you want to call up a web page *you're not in control of*, and then use JavaScript in your browser to interact with it.

The information in the original answer below is still relevant, but the question is: How do you make the code run in the right context? And the answer is: There are at least two ways:

1. Any decent browser these days has built-in debugging tools. Look on the menus for them, but in many browsers they're accessible via the <kbd>F12</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. In those tools, you'll find a "console" where you can type JavaScript and have it run in the context of the page you're looking at.

   This is great for doing things interactively, but it's a bit of a pain to retype it every time. You can also put the code in a local file (say, `/home/tjc/foo.js`) and then when you go to the page, use the console to append that script to the page (which will cause it to execute, within the context of the page), like this:

   ```
    document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = "file:///home/tjc/foo.js";
   ```
2. Once you have your script doing what you want, you might want to turn it into a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). This is a browser bookmark using the `javascript:` scheme rather than the usual `http:` and such. See the link for details. You'll want a tool that takes your JavaScript code and does the necessary URL-encoding for you, like the [Bookmarklet Crunchinator](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html) or similar.

---

**Original answer**:

> ... so that it will find text, or get element by id/class...

Those are three very different questions:

1. To find text on the page, you have a couple of options:

   1. If you only want to find the text but don't much care exactly what element contains it, you can just look through [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml) on `document.body`. `innerHTML` is a string; when you access it, the browser creates an HTML string for all of the DOM elements in the element you call it on (and its descendants). Note that this is **not** the original content from the server; this is created on-the-fly when you access the element. For a lot of use-cases, getting this string and then looking through it could be useful. Note that the text you're searching through is *markup*, so for instance, if you searched for the word "table" you might find it in a sentence ("We sat down at the table.") or in markup (`<table>...`).

      Here's an example of counting the word `I'm` on the page using `innerHTML`: [live copy](http://jsbin.com/isoxew/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/isoxew/2/edit) - See note about examples at the end.

      ```
       (function() {

         var pageText = document.body.innerHTML;
         display('Count of "I\'m" on the page: ' +
                 pageText.match(/I'm/g).length);

         function display(msg) {
           var p = document.createElement('p');
           p.innerHTML = String(msg);
           document.body.appendChild(p);
         }

       })();
      ```
   2. If you need to find out exactly what element it's in, you'll need to write a recursive function that walks through the nodes of the page and, for [`Text` nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772), looks at the text within. Here's a basic example (the function is the `walk` function): [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/isoxew) | [source](http://jsbin.com/isoxew/edit) - See note about examples at the end.

      ```
       (function() {
         var matches = [], index;

         walk(matches, document.body, "");

         function walk(matches, node, path) {
           var child;

           switch (node.nodeType) {
             case 1: // Element
               for (child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
                 walk(matches, child, path + "/" + node.tagName);
               }
               break;
             case 3: // Text
               if (node.nodeValue.indexOf("I'm") !== -1 ) {
                 matches.push("Found it at " + path);
               }
               break;
           }
         }

         display("Matches found (" + matches.length + "):");
         for (index = 0; index < matches.length; ++index) {
           display(matches[index]);
         }

         function display(msg) {
           var p = document.createElement('p');
           p.innerHTML = String(msg);
           document.body.appendChild(p);
         }

       })();
      ```
2. To find an element on the page by `id`, use [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId).
3. To find an element on the page by `class`, on most modern browsers you can use either [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall).

Note about the examples: I'm using [JSBin](http://jsbin.com), which puts the JavaScript you see on the left-hand side in the "source" view at the **end** of the HTML you see on the right (just before the closing `</body>` tag), by default. This is in keeping with [best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: think he is affused where and how to write it? TS it's so or not?

Comment: @Bas913: I suppose, but again, it's just a string property of `document.body`, so it's pretty trivial: `var pageText = document.body.innerHTML;` I've added a complete example to the answer.

Comment: TypeError: document.body is undefined (Error code: 991)
What does it mean? I need to code to execute in the iMacros

Comment: @Bas913: I have no idea what iMacros are. If you're getting an error that `document.body` is undefined in an HTML page, your code is running before the DOM has been parsed. See the note at the end of the answer, if you put your `script` tag right at the *end* of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, the `document.body` element will exist. Here's the `innerHTML` example with the code put within the HTML, for clarity: [live](http://jsbin.com/isoxew/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/isoxew/3/edit#html) I've just put the script tag where JSBin puts it for me normally.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The fact that the site is not mine and I can not edit it. I need to be able to test a simple page on the presence in it of some of the text. No need to change something in the html itself

Comment: @Bas913: Ah, I understand now. I've updated the answer with some info on that.

Comment: No, unfortunately you still do not understand me correctly: I need to write the js that runs through the three tabs and each performs the steps you need (automated autoclicker so to speak), but it depends on what the text on the page, as url is always the same. So I ask you to give me the code which searches for the page. Own operation, I had already done, but which of them to perform when I can not write. I do not need to run js for this page, I only need to undertake a search.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for imacros solution, then it'some like this:

```
 var reportDataTable = window.content.document.getElementById("yoursid");
 if (reportDataTable == null)
 {
    iimPlay("mac1.iim");
 }
 else
 {
    iimDisplay("stop!");
 }
```

Where mac1.iim is macros, which would repeated, until

> window.content.document.getElementById("yoursid");

will not be founded